# Should I use HTTP or HTTPS for image links in metatags for shares?

Tags: share, facebook-opengraph

When specifying images for twitter cards and facebook shares, which one should I use:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/logo.png" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://example.com/logo.png" />
```

or

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://example.com/logo.png" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://example.com/logo.png" />
```

?

I tried using schemaless approach:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="//example.com/logo.png" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="//example.com/logo.png" />
```

and they both failed to fetch the picture.

Comment: Is the rest of your site hosted on HTTPS?

Comment: @NateBarbettini Both HTTP and HTTPS are supported. That's why I mostly use schema agnostic links.